# docker-compose.yml content - How can i avoid "must be a mapping not a string" error message?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Problem: the below content returns "service 'image' must be a mapping not a string." 
I tried using YAML Parser(http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), but it returned no error.

```
version: 
     "2.0"

services:

 blog:

 image: 
  abc/defg
 environment:
  APPLICATION_SECRET:
   82xxxxxxx

  ports: -"9000:9000"
```

working version:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
 blog:
  image:  abc/defg
  environment:
   APPLICATION_SECRET:
    82xxx
  ports: 
   - "9000:9000"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Comment: The `image: abc/defg` must be a single line.  The `ports: -“9000:9000”` probably needs to be two lines.  YAML can be pretty picky this way.

Comment: thank you. it looks like this now; version: "2.1"
services:
 blog:
  image:  abc/defg
  environment:
   APPLICATION_SECRET:
    82xx
  ports: 
   - "9000:9000"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

Comment: YAML files are whitespace sensitive, similar to python. If you remove line feeds or change the indenting, they will not parse correctly. We will not be able to help with changes posted as comments since comments do not have linefeeds and whitespace.

Comment: @DavidMaze ".. must be a single line" Not true. The only restriction on a single line in YAML is with implicit keys, this here is a key-value pair and for that and anything else that is not just an implicit key, the specification clearly states: "In all other cases, YAML allows tokens to be separated by multi-line (possibly empty) comments."

Comment: @Anthon Thank you.  (And this is probably the same case as the more common case of block sequences and block mappings as mapping values, just with a scalar.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, there you can spread things out over multiple lines as well (as long as you properly indent the actual token). It doesn't necessarily help with readability IMO, but it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Python output that you get from the [online parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=version%3A+%0A+++++%222.0%22%0A%0Aservices%3A%0A%0A+blog%3A%0A%0A+image%3A+%0A++abc%2Fdefg%0A+environment%3A%0A++APPLICATION_SECRET%3A%0A+++82xxxxxxx%0A%0A++ports%3A+-%229000%3A9000%22&type=python), you can see that you get

```
'ports': '-"9000:9000"'
```

which doesn't look like a list of port numbers.

A sequence element is indicated by a dash followed by a space, and if you input that space after the dash following `ports`:

```
ports: - "9000:9000"
```

You actually do get an error, as block sequences that are values cannot start after the key, but must start on a line of their own:

```
ports:
- "9000:9000"
```

Although the element in the sequence have to be indented, the dash doesn't have to be, it just needs to be separated from the element by at least one space.