# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network must be a mapping, not a string

Tags: docker, jenkins

Geeting below error upon running the docker compose file/jenkins container.

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', network must be a mapping, not a string.
```

Below is the yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      -"8080":"8080"
    volume:
      -"$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
  networks:
      -net
networks:
   net
```

Docker compose verion:

```
[jenkins@localhost ~]$ docker compose -v
Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at the following question as it seems similar to yours, [docker-compose.yml content - How can i avoid "must be a mapping not a string" error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948084/docker-compose-yml-content-how-can-i-avoid-must-be-a-mapping-not-a-string-er). Also, check the following docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Comment: For most practical uses you should be able to delete the `networks:` blocks entirely, and use the `default` network Compose provides for you.  YAML in general is extremely sensitive to whitespace so make sure you have enough spaces in the right places (for example, I think there needs to be a space after `-`).